# How can I place an arrayOfString datatype inside a php associative array

Tags: php, web-services

I'm learning php trying to get data from a wsdl service.  The service method I'm requesting data from requires two parameters, one of which requires an arrayOfstring type.  So somehow I'm needing to pass a value like this ACCT_ID[0] to the soapClient method.  Here are the parameters the method requires:

```
<s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ACCT_ID" type="tns:ArrayOfString"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="UserNumber" type="s:long"/>
    </s:sequence>
```

The ACCT_ID requires an arrayOfString type passed to it through the PHP soapclient.  I'm stuck on how this is done.  This is where I'm at so far:

```
$client = new soapClient('http://webservice/accountdata.asmx?wsdl', array('trace' => 1));

    //method paramaters
    $user_num = 20;

    $acct_id = "98765431654654654656, 44986532156469898442";
    $ACCT_ID = explode(" ", $acct_id);

    $params = array("ACCT_ID" => $ACCT_ID[0], "UserNumber" => $user_num);


    $response = $client->Account_Data($params);
```

so I've got the soapClient object with a method Account_Data and I'm passing $params to it.  I've tested it with these parameters using the Storm tool and I did get the proper xml response.  And I can see in the browser source that UserNumber is being sent to the webservice, but not ACCT_ID[0].  I've tried all sorts of things, but I'm not sure where to go from here.  How can I pass an arrayOfString type parameter to the webservice through php?  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Convert the parameter into a json string.

```
$acct_id = array(806796224000,000000000000);
$ACCT_ID = json_encode($acct_id);
```